# Heroku-deployed flask app does not update consistently based on server data

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have deployed an app for a school project with basically takes in a user's handwritten digit and then shows the digit on a screen based on some machine learning algorithm.

The user's handwritten digit is stored as a 28x28 JavaScript array and is sent back to the flask app through a post request:

```
submit_button.onclick = () => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      window.location.replace("/");
    }
  };
  xhr.open("POST", "/submit");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(printGrid()));
  clearGrid();
};
```

The Flask app then processes the array through a function and updates a global variable `digit` based on the output of the function:

```
@app.route("/submit", methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    global digit
    digit = process_digit(request.get_json())
    return "ok"
```

The "/" route then returns an updated html template with the digit.

In the development server the webpage does what I expect it to do and only reloads once the digit has been processed based on the `xhr.onreadystatechange` I set in the JavaScript file.

However, when deployed to heroku, the webpage reloads a short while after the submit button has been pressed but sometimes the digit shown on the screen would not be updated and I would have to do 1 - 3 reloads for it to show to correct value.

Is there anything I could do to solve this issue? I'm new to web development so if anyone could point me to the right resources or point out the mistakes I have made that would be very much appreciated!

**EDIT**:

Maybe in short what I would like to ask is this: what is the best way to take input from the user using javascript i.e. the 2D array, send it to a python program for processing and then update the webpage properly based on the output from the python program?

Comment: Heroku servers sleep every 30 mins (If you are on the free plan) I suggest you read this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393815/possible-to-bypass-herokus-free-plans-sleeps-after-30-mins-of-inactivity-wit] 
as it can hold some insight to help you formulate a better question or edit the existing one

Comment: Sorry for being unclear with my question, I will edit the post.